# How to edit nginx ingress config in kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, logging, lua, kubernetes

I need to implement logging for kubernetes ingress installation so all request will be logging with the following details:

- Request headers
- Request body
- Response headers
- Response body

I understand that I can edit `log_format` of nginx using [ConfigMap](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configmap.md), however, for logging response body, I need to use lua (something like [this](https://gist.github.com/morhekil/1ff0e902ed4de2adcb7a)).

In this case, I should have possibility to add this lua code in every server section of nginx config. What is the most easy way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you deploying your ingress controller?

Comment: any news @Eduard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I need to use custom nginx template. In general, the steps should be as following:

1. Obtain the `nginx.tmpl` from the ingress-nginx controller that is located at `/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl`
2. Edit it according to your needs
3. Map it using volumes

The detailed instruction is located [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/custom-template.md)

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Looks like the file was moved in the repo to [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template.md)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to configure the nginx Ingress controller using a ConfigMap, you need [to create the ConfigMap that will hold those values](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/customization#using-configmaps).

The nginx ingress controller [will use whatever value you specify in the `LogFormat` key of the `ConfigMap`](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/nginx-controller/nginx/templates/nginx.tmpl#L32). So you should be able to edit the configMap and change the LogFormat key to specify the format you want. I haven't actually tried this command, but it should be something like

```
kubectl patch configmap nginx-config -p '{"LogFormat":\'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_time <"$request_body" >"$resp_body"\'}'
```

Comment: Hi @fiunchinho. Sorry for not answering such long time. I am afraid, it is not what I need exactly. I understand that I can edit log parameter of Nginx config using configMap, but what I need is just having separate lua section added (exactly like in [this](https://gist.github.com/morhekil/1ff0e902ed4de2adcb7a#file-nginx-conf-L9) config) Is it possible to edit Nginx config with not just replacing some params, but adding specific sections?

Comment: I don't think so :/